# Drools: how to implement and ( && ) condition inside not expression?

Tags: java, drools

I have the following rule :

```
rule " data value > 50 for 10 seconds "
dialect "java"
when
    data: MyData(name.contains("double") && getValue()> 50) from entry-point "dataEntryPoint"   
    not(
        myData(this.name==dataName,
        getValue() < 50 ,
        this after[0,10s] data ) from entry-point "dataEntryPoint" )
    
then
    doSmthg();
end
```

The data type is included in the name and I want to write this rule only on double values.
However, it seems that in the second expression ( inside the not) , **getValue()** is being called even when this.name **!=** dataName which causes an error since the value is a String.

Basically, I want it to only evaluate getValue() if the first condition is true ( && ).

I'm only having this issue when I add the not() condition.

When I remove it, the getValue() > 50 is only evaluated when the first condition is true.

```
rule " data value > 50 for 10 seconds "
dialect "java"
when
    data: MyData(name.contains("double") && getValue()> 50) from entry-point "dataEntryPoint"   
    
then
    doSmthg();
end
```

Comment: This really sounds like a problem you should be solving by fixing your model instead of hacking a solution into your rules.

Comment: Also as a tip, you don't need to do `getValue()` ; instead you can do `value`. Eg. `MyData( value > 50 )`. Drools will find the getter and use it (or use the variable directly if it is public.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, it works only when both parts of `&&` operator are constraints of the same variable.

```
rule "data value > 50 for 10 seconds"
dialect "java"
when
    data: MyData(name contains "double" && value > 50) from entry-point "dataEntryPoint"   
    not(
        MyData(name == data.name, 
        value instanceof Number && value < 50,
        this after[0,10s] data) from entry-point "dataEntryPoint")
then
    System.out.println("alert");
end
```